# Reason for use of unassigned local variable error

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering why the compiler gives me this error. The try block will be executed every time the function is called and that means the variable will get assigned. But still it doesn't let me compile.

```
using System;

namespace Checking
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int intNum;
            intNum = readValue("Please enter a number: ");

        }
        static int readValue(string strPrompt)
        {
            int intRes;
            Console.WriteLine(strPrompt);
            try
            {
                intRes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());   // Gets assigned here! But still doesnt allow me to compile!

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric value.\n");
                readValue(strPrompt);
            }
            return intRes;    
        }
    }
}
```

Putting return intRes inside the try block allows me to get rid of that error, but then an error crops up saying not all code paths return a value. I understand the errors, but I still don't understand why it won't allow me to compile, the try block gets executed every time right?

I also know that assigning 0 to intRes will get rid of that error.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is right. The variable is not always assigned.

If the conversion fails, the assignment never happens, and the execution continues inside the catch block, where you call the function again, but you have forgotten to assign the return value of that call to the variable:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric value.\n");
  intRes = readValue(strPrompt);
}
```

---

Here's an anternative implementation using a `while` and `TryParse`:

```
static int readValue(string strPrompt) {
  int intRes = 0;
  bool done = false;
  while (!done) {
    Console.WriteLine(strPrompt);
    if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out intRes) {
      done = true;
    } else {
      Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric value.\n");
    }
  }
  return intRes;    
}
```

Comment: @AbijeetPatro - Yes, this is the direct answer. But a recursive ReadValue() is not a very good idea.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: I added an alternative implementation above.

Comment: @Guffa Is there any performance difference between a while and a recursion? A while loop certainly looks better.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: No, there is no difference that matters in this case. When you are using recursion as a loop, it causes a limitation on the number of iterations, as the stack space is limited. It's however high enough that it won't be a problem when you are doing user input like that (the user will give up before the stack runs out), but in other situations it may be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Because if the try fails, intRes has no value

In your catch use

```
intRes = readValue(strPrompt);
```

Initialise it with

```
int intRes = 0;
```

instead of

```
int intRes;
```

You may also want to look at the `int.TryParse` syntax

Comment: @Oded: Actually it won't. It's a local variable, so it's allocated on the stack, and it's not initialised to any specific value.

Comment: But if it fails, the control will never get to the end right? It's recursive, it will only get to the end if the try block doesn't throw an exception. I guess the compiler isn't smart enough to figure that out...for now.

Comment: Initialising the varible to zero means that the function will always return zero if the first conversion fails.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: Not correct. If the convert failes, the control goes to the catch block and after the catch block it goes to the `return intRes;` If you would change the last line of your catch block to `return readValue(strPrompt);`, the message would also go away without the need for an initialization of `intRes`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, Yea this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If `Convert.ToInt32` failes, `intRes` never gets assigned to.

Either set a default value when creating the variable, or assign to in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

You will get an uninitialized `intRes` if `Console.ReadLine()` throws an exception. That is why your compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has no way to know if your code inside the try block will throw an exception or not.
So, in case your code throws an exception, then the intRes variable will never be assigned.

Consequently the compiler emits the error message.

Also, as it stands, your code has a problem. You try to recursively call readValue inside the catch block to get a correct value but when your user finally enter a correct value, the main will never receive the value entered because you are using a local variable for the result value.